# Not uniform feature space

Tags: machine-learning, data-manipulation, data-extraction, data-processing

I'm making a machine learning algorithm for predicting interest rates. The problem that I'm dealing with consists of different features' format for old records.
More in detail: for old contracts(records), one of the features, that is the matrix of prices, have 15x12 cells conversely the new ones have 14x15 elements. The reason is due to changes in the financial markets.

Now the problem is that I was doing PCA on a subset of uniform matrixes in order to do standardization and dimensionality reduction, and there were no problems. Does anyone of you know how can I reach the same objectives in this new context ?

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: What are the context changes?  It looks like you used to have 15 contracts with 12 features each; now you have 14 contracts with 15 features each.  How many of the features are the same?  Are you looking to merge the data sets, or run a totally new PCA?  If the latter, what has changed that keeps you from simply applying the same process?

Comment: rows denote expiry time ( when the contract starts ) and columns the tenor ( how long it is ) . Each record describe also other features time dependent , so I cannot merge different records without loss of information.
What I'm thinking on, is split the dataset into different currencies and apply the a sort of Cross Validation or Bagging; in order to exploit all the information. What do you think about this idea ?

Comment: I think that bagging is a good way to handle this; cross-validation will fill in the blanks thereafter.

Comment: Just to propose another solution, consider to interpolate between matrix in order to go to an uniform feature space. ( Here the problem occurs when is not possible to interpolate but extrapolaions are required ). 
In this way the developed algorithm will use all the data at the same time.